# jquery problems with toggle in combination with .click() and .hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a problem when I'm using .click() and .hover() in combination with toggle.

I have a "menu" which should be opened/closed on hover, but can also be closed/reopened on click. But if I'm opening the menu with hover and then close it with a click, it opens again If i stop hovering it.

Here's my code ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tsLwLdkj/1/))

HTML

```
<ul>
<li><span>Click Me</span>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $("ul").hover(function() {
        $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });
    $("ul").click(function() {
       $(this).find('ul').toggle();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
ul{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: relative;
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
}

ul ul{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: -1px;
}

span{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

a{
    background-color: #eee;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
}

a:hover{
    background-color: white;
}
```

I know what the problem is, but I don't know how to fix it. I hope someone has a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write two hover function for mouse in and out instead of using `toggle` like below :

```
$(function() {
        $("ul").hover(function() {
            $(this).find('ul').show();
        },function() {
            $(this).find('ul').hide();
        });
        $("ul").click(function() {
           $(this).find('ul').toggle();
        });
    });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/tsLwLdkj/2/)**

Comment: Okay, that works great! Thanks :) Do you know how I can change the behaviour on a tablet that I need a "double tap" because of the hover effect.

Comment: you mean you want to use double click instead of click?

Comment: Yep, I don't like it that a tablet user has to click 2 times.

Answer (score 2):

Use the first hover constructor:

```
$("ul").hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

...instead of second which has same function for both operations:

```
.hover( handlerInOut )
```

Regards ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {
   $("ul").hover(function() {
     $(this).find('ul').show();
   }, 
   function(){
     $(this).find('ul').hide()
   });
   $("ul").click(function() {
     $(this).find('ul').toggle();
   });
});
```

Add mouseout function also in your hover function.

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/6jzdgcap/

Answer (score 2):

You may also prefer to use mouseenter (http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and mouseleave (http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) if you find this easier to read.

```
    $(function() {
        $("ul")
        .mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).find('ul').show();
        })
        .mouseleave(function() { 
           $(this).find('ul').hide(); 
        });

        $("ul").click(function() {
           $(this).find('ul').toggle();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) which creates the issue, You can use [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) and [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) separately in the callbacks functions of [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) as follows:

```
$(function () {
     $("ul").hover(function () {
            $(this).find('ul').slideDown();
     },
     function () {
            $(this).find('ul').slideUp();
     });

     $("ul").click(function () {
            $(this).find('ul').toggle();
     });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/tsLwLdkj/4/)